# Multiple Url for same app in tomcat to test multi tenancy

Tags: java, tomcat, multi-tenant

I have developed a multi tenant application with Java on tomcat 8. I want to test it now. Is there a way where I can replicate/create different urls pointing to same application in tomcat? i.e. like following manner.

`https://abc.localhost:8080/myapp`

and

`https://xyz.localhost:8080/myapp`

The reason for abc and xyz, is they would be the sub domain for the application. Using which I will be able to identify the tenants.

P.S I don't want to use cookie based approach and don't want to keep passing or ask the user to enter the tenant name or tenant id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your hosts file to test this. Change your Tomcat HTTP port to 80 and edit your host file :

> 127.0.0.1 abc.localhost 
>   127.0.0.1 xyz.localhost

on Linux : /etc/hosts
On Windows : C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc

I use this to test my multi-tenant application, that also use subdomain for each tenant. (I use WildFly as Application Server)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a solution to this without the need to point my application to port 80.

I used `fiddler` for this. In fiddler you can change rules. From the menu Rules -> Customize Rules.

Selecting customizing Rules will open a script, in which there are number of methods predefined, `OnBeforeRequest` ,`OnBeforeResponse` etc. I modified `OnBeforeRequest` and added following lines of code.

```
if (oSession.host=="www.mysubdomain1.maindomain.com:8443") {
    oSession.host="localhost:8443";
}

if (oSession.host=="www.mysubdomain2.maindomain.com:8443") {
    oSession.host="localhost:8443";
}
```

and that is it. You can map it to your app as per your wish.

The fiddler documentation link is: [Fiddler Script documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/115282/can-i-configure-the-windows-hosts-file-to-use-ip-address-plus-port)